# Solr index is not updating with publish

Tags: events, indexing, solr, sitecore, publish

Using Sitecore 10.0.1
Solr 8.4

I published few items.
There are 3 servers and each server are pointing to different solrs, say A,B,C.
But No publishing changes are updating in Solr indexes B and C. I checked event queue tables and it is updating there.

Comment: Normally only 1 server pushes changes to Solr. If there are more Solr servers, there may be Solr Replication configured. Without detailed information how your environment is setup, no one will be able to help you.

Comment: yes one server is connected to one solr only. this works fine. but in another server connected to a different solr, there indexes are not updated

Answer (score 1):

If you have a geo-distributed setup with Sitecore servers in multiple regions and a Solr server for each region, you should make sure that **one Sitecore server in each region** has `Indexing` role in the `web.config` file. It can be a Content Management server or Content Delivery server depending on your environment configuration.

Here is an example of how the `Indexing` role can be added to `web.config`:

```
<add key="role:define" value="ContentManagement, Indexing"/>
```

See more details in Sitecore documentation [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/100/platform-administration-and-architecture/enable-the-indexing-sub-role.html).